# where_not_in code in CI models

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hello coders i am trying to code this mysql script in CODE IGNITER model but not getting the correct script how to code it into active record can u please help me

```
SELECT bus_reg_number
FROM t_bus_detail
WHERE bus_reg_number NOT
IN (

SELECT bus_reg_number
FROM t_bus_alot
)
```

MY MODEL

```
 public function get_bus_reg_number()
    {


    $this->db->select('bus_reg_number')->from('t_bus_detail');
 $result=$this->db->where_not_in('bus_reg_number' NOT IN (SELECT 'bus_reg_number' FROM 't_bus_alot')');



    $dropdown_bus_number = array();
    foreach($result as $r) 
    {
    $dropdown_bus_number[$r['bus_reg_number']] = $r['bus_reg_number'];

    }
    return $dropdown_bus_number;
    }
```

Comment: Show your model function where you try to get the result..

Comment: public function get_bus_reg_number()
 {
 
 
 $this->db->select('bus_reg_number')->from('t_bus_detail');
 $result=$this->db->where_not_in('bus_reg_number' NOT IN (SELECT 'bus_reg_number' FROM 't_bus_alot')');
 
 
 
    $dropdown_bus_number = array();
    foreach($result as $r) 
 {
    $dropdown_bus_number[$r['bus_reg_number']] = $r['bus_reg_number'];
     
 }
    return $dropdown_bus_number;
    }

Comment: edit your question and put it there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('bus_reg_number');
$this->db->from('t_bus_detail');
$this->db->where('`bus_reg_number` NOT IN (SELECT `bus_reg_number` FROM `t_bus_alot`)', NULL, FALSE);
```

Try this.. the null and false will say to CI not to escape your where query..

Edit : here is plain query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT bus_reg_number FROM t_bus_detail WHERE bus_reg_number NOT IN (SELECT bus_reg_number FROM t_bus_alot)");
$dropdown_bus_number = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
   $dropdown_bus_number[$row['bus_reg_number']] = $row['bus_reg_number'];
}
```

Comment: i am finding error
Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: models/transport_bus_system.php

Line Number: 28


I AM POSTING MY WHOLE FUNCTION

 public function get_bus_reg_number()
 {
 
 
 $this->db->select('bus_reg_number')->from('t_bus_detail');
 $result=$this->db->where('`bus_reg_number` NOT IN (SELECT `bus_reg_number` FROM `t_bus_alot`)', NULL, FALSE);
 
    $dropdown_bus_number = array();
    foreach($result as $r) 
 {
    $dropdown_bus_number[$r['bus_reg_number']] = $r['bus_reg_number'];
     
 }
    return $dropdown_bus_number;
    }

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0














 I AM POSTING MY WHOLE FUNCTION public function get_bus_reg_number() { $this->db->select('bus_reg_number')->from('t_bus_detail'); $result=$this->db->where('bus_reg_number NOT IN (SELECT bus_reg_number FROM t_bus_alot)', NULL, FALSE); $dropdown_bus_number = array(); foreach($result as $r) { $dropdown_bus_number[$r['bus_reg_number']] = $r['bus_reg_number']; } return $dropdown_bus_number; } 

Filename: models/transport_bus_system.php

Line Number: 28